# How do I add an svg file on S3 in a div

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG file on my S3 server and I want to put that in a div?

I have seen example of how to use the coordinates like this

```
    <div id="inner_container">
        <svg height="6" width="6">
            <path d="M 0 6 L 3 0 L 6 6 L 0 6"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

But I want something like this.

```
     <div id="inner_container">
        <svg height="6" width="6" url="/photo.svg">
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use an `<object>`, `<iframe>` or `<img>` tag.

Comment: Not sure how this is related with Amazon S3 ... HTML/CSS/SVG yes.